# Replacing explicit recursion with higher-order functions

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have the following code, which is designed to take a list of `a`'s , and list of `b`'s, and return all pairings [(a, b)], such that

- Each `a` and each `b` only appears once in each pairing.
- Each pair `(a, b)` meets some condition `cond`, i.e. `cond :: a -> b -> Bool`.

For example, the result for the lists [1, 2] [x,y,z] should be

```
[[(1, x), (2, y)]
 [(1, x), (2, z)]
 [(1, y), (2, x)]
 [(1, y), (2, z)]
 [(1, z), (2, x)]
 [(1, z), (2, y)]]
```

Here is some (somewhat abstracted) code that that does the job with explicit recursion, but I'd like to replace it with a fold or something similar. Any tips?

```
someFn :: [a] -> [b] -> [ [(a, b)] ]
someFn [] _ = []
someFn (a : as) bs = [ [(a,b)] ++ rest | b <- bs, rest <- someFn as (bs \\ [b]), cond a b]
```

Comment: `[(a, b)]` is a list of pairs, so your function is returning a list of lists of pairs rather than a list of pairs.

Comment: "Each a and each b only appears once in each pairing" - well, it might be because english is not my first language, but is this not trivially alwas true for any pair (tuple) (a,b)? a occurs at most once, b accurs at most once.

Comment: It's not very clear what your goal is.  Do you want to replace this with a fold or are you asking how to make `someFn` higher order?  If the latter, higher order on what?  The `cond` predicate?

Comment: foo x y with = filter (uncurry with) [(a,b) | a <- x, b <- y]

Comment: I see you are taking care of duplicates in the second list, but what about the first?

Comment: Only once, but can be zero, or at least and only once?

Comment: Sorry - I've added an example that should clarify things.

Comment: @JB each `a` has to appear, but some `b`'s can eb left out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can comprehend from your explanation is you want to filter based on some condition on the product of two list. It is easy to take product of lists using list comprehension and then the filter function will reduce the product to only pairs satisfying the given condition

```
foo :: [a] -> [b] -> (a -> b -> Bool)-> [(a,b)]
foo x y with = filter (uncurry with) [(a,b) | a <- x, b <- y]
```

[Update according to edit]

This produces the list like you want (hopefully)

```
bar :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a,b)]]
bar xs ys = map (zip xs) $ permutations ys
```

To filter on the given condition

```
biz :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> [[(a,b)]] -> [[(a,b)]]
biz = map . filter . uncurry
```

Comment: I've made some edits to the original question which I hope make it clearer. The original output type [ [(a,b)] ] was correct, and is necessary to deal with the duplicate issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `foldr` to refactor your code as follows:

```
delete :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
delete index xs = let (ys, _:zs) = splitAt index xs in ys ++ zs

ifoldr :: (Int -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
ifoldr f acc xs = foldr (\(a, b) c -> f a b c) acc $ zip [0..] xs

someFn :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b] -> [[(a,b)]]
someFn _ [] _ = [[]]
someFn cond (a:as) bs = ifoldr (\index b acc -> if cond a b
    then concat [map ((a,b):) . someFn cond as $ delete index bs, acc]
    else acc) [] bs
```

Note that the edge case is `someFn _ [] _ = [[]]` which is in accordance with the type definition of the function `someFn :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b] -> [[(a,b)]]`.

You may use `someFn` as follows:

```
someFn (\a b -> True) [1,2] "xyz"

-- [[(1,'x'),(2,'y')],
--  [(1,'x'),(2,'z')],
--  [(1,'y'),(2,'x')],
--  [(1,'y'),(2,'z')],
--  [(1,'z'),(2,'x')],
--  [(1,'z'),(2,'y')]]

someFn (\a b -> case (a,b) of (1,'x') -> False
                              (2,'y') -> False
                              otherwise -> True) [1,2] "xyz"

-- [[(1,'y'),(2,'x')],
--  [(1,'y'),(2,'z')],
--  [(1,'z'),(2,'x')]]
```

Hope that helps.